# Passing maps to functions via pointers or reference?

Tags: c++, pointers, reference

I have the following question:
What is the right way of passing a map (or a vector etc.) to a function in c++ when passing by value or const reference is not an option because the map has to be changed within the function and the changes should be seen also outside of the function?

My function `test1` causes a segmentation fault 11. Does this happen because the pointer obviously does not carry any size information?

Function `test2` works as it should but flymake-google-cpplint says "Is this a non-const reference? If so, make const or use a pointer".

```
#include <iostream>
#include <map>
using namespace std;

void test1(map<int, int> *memo) {
  auto it = memo->find(1);
}

void test2(map<int, int> &memo) {

}

int main() {

  map<int, int> *memo;
  memo->insert(make_pair(1,1));

  return 0;
}
```

What solution would you recommend?

Thanks a lot

M

Comment: what's wrong with passing by reference?

Comment: You can do either, passing by reference just makes things a little easier to read (usually). Maybe it's just personal preference but I also prefer typing just `.` to `->`.

Comment: Unless you want to be able to have a null parameter prefer pass by reference.

Comment: It seems like it's a question about the Google C++ Style Guide rather than a c++ question. There's nothing wrong with taking a non-`const` reference argument if that's what's needed.

Comment: Uninitialised pointer == undefined behaviour.

Comment: This is sort of an opinion poll, I think. @NathanOliver already made the point that passing a pointer lets you pass null. Otherwise passing by reference is the obvious choice.

Comment: This is a matter of opinion. The correct opinion is to pass by non-const reference. The incorrect opinion is to pass a pointer.

Answer (score 2):

First thing is that you have an error in your code.

```
map<int, int> *memo;
```

is never initialized, which is why you get segmentation fault. What you actually want is to skip the pointer

```
map<int, int> memo;
```

and pass the object either by reference or the pointer to the object (`test1(&memo);`).

The reason you get the warning from *flymake-google-cpplint* is because the use of non-constant references makes it unclear whether or not the object will be mutated (changed), see [here](https://github.com/google/benchmark/issues/394) for more info.

I would ignore the warning from *flymake-google-cpplint* and use the non-constant reference. This is mostly a subjective thing and as long as you are consistent with using `const` the intended use of your functions should be clear.

Answer (score 1):

You try to insert to uninitialized pointer to `map<int, int>`

```
map<int, int> *memo;
memo->insert(make_pair(1,1));
```

Pass by reference, there is nothing wrong with that.